# How is it possible to set a directory permission, so the group can both read and write files in it? (Regardless who created a file)

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown, chgrp

I created a directory, which is owned by the `www-data` group. I would like to make the files in it writeable by the members of the group, no matter who created the file. My username is `pi`. I tried it like this:

```bsh
mkdir ./shared
sudo chown pi ./shared
sudo chgrp www-data ./shared
sudo chmod -R 770 ./shared
sudo chmod g+sw ./shared
```

If I check it with `ls -l`, it looks like this:

```
drwxrws--- 2 pi   www-data 4096 sept 28 17:10  shared
```

I created a new file in it:

```
cd ./shared
touch ./test.txt
```

But if I check, the group has no write right for the new `test.txt`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi www-data 0 sept 28 17:10 test.txt
```

What do I wrong? I can not run `sudo chmod -R 770 ./shared` each time, a new file is created in the directory by a script/webserver.

How is it possible to create a shared directory, where both the owner and the group members have read and write rights for the files, regardless who created a specific file?

Comment: What is the value of your `umask`?

Comment: Even if I set my umask to 002, calling `sudo -u www-data touch ./foo.txt` creates a file, which is not group-writeable

Answer (score 0):

If the system and file-system supports posix-draft-type ACLs, you can do:

```
setfacl -m d:g::rw ./shared
```

For newly created files in there to be automatically given read+write permission to the group, even if the `umask` of the processes creating those files would normally not grant those permissions.

In any case, that doesn't stop users from removing those permissions with `chmod`/`setfacl` afterwards.